# Static Classes, Methods and main()

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

So, I'm a java noob and i just came across something that confused me. Getting to the point, I made a Foo Class and made an instance:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo("Foo");
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Foo(String A)
    {
        System.out.println(A);
    }
}
```

I noted that the Foo Class doesn't have to be static. Why? Whereas

if i do this

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo("Foo");
    }
    static class Foo
    {
        public Foo(String A)
        {
            System.out.println(A);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it HAS to be static. Why the difference? Static means it's instance independent hence every thing that is used in a static method also has to be instance independent(?) With Foo I was creating the instance in the static method so Foo didn't need to be static. But then what difference does having the class inside make? I thought i'd got the concept of static down. but apparently i lack a lot of concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by [JLS-8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) which says (in part)

> An *inner class* is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared `static`.
>
> An inner class may be a non-`static` member class ([§8.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5)), a local class ([§14.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)), or an anonymous class ([§15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)). A member class of an interface is implicitly `static` ([§9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5)) so is never considered to be an inner class.

A static class is thus not an inner class, and an inner class requires an *instance* of the enclosing class; like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Main().new Foo("Foo");
    }
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(String A)
        {
            System.out.println(A);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second code snippet, `Foo` is nested inside `Main`. Nested classes can be either inner classes or static. If they are inner classes (non static), each instance of the inner class must be associated with an instance of the enclosing class.

Therefore, if you remove the `static` keyword from `Foo` class in the second snippet, you'll have to instantiate it with :

```
Foo foo = new Main().new Foo("Foo");
```

When the nested class is static, it doesn't require an instance of the enclosing class, and you can instantiate it with

```
Foo foo = new Foo("Foo");
```

On the other hand, in your first snippet, `Foo` is not nested inside `Main`, so you don't need an instance of `Main` in order to instantiate it. And it cannot be static, since top level classes can't be static.

> I thought i'd got the concept of static down. but apparently i lack a lot of concepts.

When applied to nested classes, the `static` keyword has a different meaning than it has when applied to methods and variables. You should read about nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

Java is an Object Oriented programming language.

If you need a non-static declaration, field, method etc. from a class you need to create an instance from this class.

But to access static fields, methods you do not need to create an instance.

Now have a look at your example;

1.Main and Foo is different classes so you can create an instance from Foo everywhere.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo("Foo");
    }
}

class Foo {
    public Foo(String A) {
        System.out.println(A);
    }
}
```

2.Foo is an inner class and Foo class is never accessible if an instance of Main not created. So If you create a Main instance you can create Foo too. But without creating a Main instance, only accessing Foo is defining Foo class as static

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo("Foo");
    }

    static class Foo {
        public Foo(String A) {
            System.out.println(A);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the top example, you have two independent classes in the same file. `main` can reference `Foo` because it's just another class.

In the bottom example, you have a static nested class. It's also able to be instantiated independently. If you got rid of the `static` keyword on `Foo` you'd have an inner class, tied to a particular instance of `Main`, but when you are running the static `main` method there is no particular instance of `Main` to reference.

This reference might help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

In java, we can’t make Top level class static. Only nested classes can be static.
So,For 1st scenario you will not be able to make the Foo class as static.
for the 2nd Scenario Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class.